# Getting exception that column is not yet created in database

Tags: java, android

When I insert data into my table, I get an error that a certain column is not yet created. Here this my exception that I'm getting

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contact_table has no column named naame (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contact_table(naame) VALUES (?)

This is my databasehandler class

```
public class My_Data_Base_Handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public My_Data_Base_Handler(Context context){
        super(context, Constant_Variable.DB_NAME,null,Constant_Variable.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create = "CREATE TABLE " + Constant_Variable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + Constant_Variable.KEY_ID+ "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"+
                Constant_Variable.KEY_NAME+"TEXT,"+Constant_Variable.KEY_PHONE +"TEXT " + ");";
        Log.d("msg ","msg is "+create);
        db.execSQL(create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void add_Contact(Contacts contacts){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constant_Variable.KEY_PHONE,contacts.getPhone_No());
        values.put(Constant_Variable.KEY_NAME,contacts.getName());

        db.insert(Constant_Variable.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<Contacts> getAllContacts(){
        ArrayList<Contacts> contact_list=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        String select="SELECT * FROM "+Constant_Variable.TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(select,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Contacts contacts=new Contacts();
                contacts.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                contacts.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                contacts.setPhone_No(cursor.getString(2));
                contact_list.add(contacts);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contact_list;
    }
}
```

I don't know that where I'm going wrong when I add data in it, I get this exception that a certain column is not yet created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no column named **naame**

Probably just a typo?

In case you modified the columns recently, try increasing `Constant_Variable.DB_VERSION` and change `onUpgrade` to:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constant_Variable.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Btw.. do **not** call `db.close()` ! Bad for performance!